# Ler ficheiro localizado noutro Package

Tags: java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho 3 packages, um onde está localizada a classe do gui, outra onde vai ser os "scripts" de leitura de dados (no main) e fotos e ficheiros de texto nos resources.

```
    File file = new File("/com/Convocatoria/resources/DB.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

Vou usar o scanner para ler o ficheiro no entanto dá me o erro

> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: Essa hierarquia q vc ta usando nao existe na imagem. Por isso o erro.

Comment: @Articuno Como assim? Está ali o resources e a convocatoria

Comment: Não existe nenhum packace "com".

Comment: @Articuno Não é necessário dizer com antes do "nome do projeto"?

Comment: Se você não tem nenhum pacote com no projeto, porque precisaria citar algo que nao existe?

Comment: com, só seria preciso se fosse um package...   o fato de existier sempre com como package é porque a Oracle recomendava a organização dos  pacotes com o nome do site ao inverso...  www.google.com.br

os pacotes seriam br/com/google

Comment: @Articuno Ok, muito obrigado!

Comment: @AndréMoreira só um adendo, voce nao tem apenas 3 packages, voce tem na verdade 4, `Convocatoria` tambem e um package que comporta o outros 3. Ah, se a resposta lhe ajudou, voce pode aceita-la, clicando no `v` a esquerda assim a resposta serve de referencia como solucao para outros que a encontrarem em pesquisa.

Answer (score 3):

O erro é causado pela hierarquia de pacotes informada como caminho na classe. Pelo print, não há nenhum pacote "com" ou nenhum pacote com isso no nome, portanto, esse path informado é inexistente no projeto.

Você deve informar o caminho até o arquivo, sempre seguindo sua herarquia de pacotes, no caso, apenas `/Convocatoria/resources/DB.txt` seria suficiente:

```
File file = new File("/Convocatoria/resources/DB.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

Nao existe obrigatoriedade em informar *com* em java, isso é apenas uma convencao que se herdou do android, pra organizar a hierarquia, mas se voce nao seguir, nao precisa usar na hora de passar o caminho de algum arquivo.